# CASE WHEN ON 3 Months Back

Tags: oracle, date, case

I am getting an error on this code below. my goal is to count anyone who fits a criteria on three months back from specified date.

```
, COUNT(DISTINCT case when instr(proc_concat,'297.7') and 
  (BetweenDate -3 months) then RECIPIENT end) AS TCOUNTH
```

The  (BetweenDate -3 months) is the tricky part. I am operating within a yearly window not 3 months back from getDate () i need it to be three months back from within -3 months of Y.   Any ideas? Thanks.

Modified:

```
CREATE TABLE MONTH3LOOK AS Select 
to_CHAR(DATE_OF_SERVICE_3013,'YYYY-MM') "Date"

,COUNT(DISTINCT case when (regexp_instr(IS_CONCAT,'(2957|29570|29571|29572|29573|29574|29575|29576|29577|29578|29579)')>0)
 and 
 (DATE_OF_SERVICE_3013 between trunc(DATE_OF_SERVICE_3013,'MM') and add_months(trunc(DATE_OF_SERVICE_3013,'MM'),-3))
then USER end) AS Recip


FROM .NET_SERVICE
WHERE DATE_OF_SERVICE_3013 BETWEEN 
TO_DATE('2013-10','YYYY-MM') AND 
TO_DATE('2014-03','YYYY-MM')

group by to_CHAR(DATE_OF_SERVICE_3013,'YYYY-MM')
```

IS there a a quicker way to query this.... im just testing it and it takes about 2 hours. All I want to answer is: Count users who have IS_DIA within 3 months look from month X to month X-3 on a rolling scale. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to mention what the error was that you were getting... Also, I would suggest you look up the `months_between()` function, which seems to be the one you're after (you'd be comparing your date column with sysdate, presumably). Or possibly `your_date_column between add_months(sysdate, -3) and sysdate`.

Answer (score 0):

```
COUNT(DISTINCT case when instr(proc_concat,'297.7') and 
DATE_COLUMN > add_months(sysdate, -3); then RECIPIENT end) AS TCOUNTH
```

Where date_column is the field you're comparing against.

Comment: Can i just use Date_column... given it might be 2 years ago I want the count to just laymen:  (be date_column or three months back)

Comment: Can I do  

COUNT(DISTINCT case when instr(proc_concat,'297.7') and 
DATE_COLUMN > last_day(add_months(DATE_COLUMN,-90)) then RECIPIENT end) AS TCOUNTH